# Banach-Tarski nonparadox: Reassembling a ball into two balls with a total volume equal to the original volume

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The Banach-Tarski paradox states that a ball can be partitioned into finitely many pieces which can be rotated and translated into two balls identical to the original one.

But can a ball be partitioned into finitely many pieces which can be rotated and translated to form two balls with non-zero radiuses such that the sum of their volumes is equal to the original volume? If yes, can this be done without choice?

Comment: Banach's trick was to dissect the unit ball into carefully constructed sets which are not measurable.

Comment: So... you want to cut the ball into two balls such that the sum of their volumes is the original one? Why should this be a serious problem?

Comment: No, you dissect a ball in a finite number of sets and only by means of translation and rotation you move these sets in a way that in the end you have 2 balls, both having the same volume as the original one. That is serious. And called a paradox.

Comment: @Asaf It is not immediately clear to me that this is possible with measurable pieces. Is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special case of a problem posed by Tarski and Wagon who asked if for any pair of measurable subsets $A, B\subset R^n$ of the same (positive) volume, there is a subdivision of $A, B$ into measurable subsets $A_1,...,A_k$, $B_1,...,B_k$ such that $A_i$ is congruent (via translations) to $B_i$, $i=1,...,k$. This question has an affirmative answer (assuming that $A, B$ are bounded and their boundaries satisfy a certain technical condition) given in

M. Laczkovich, [Decomposition of sets with small boundary](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s2-46.1.58). J. London Math. Soc. (2) 46 (1992), no. 1, 58–64.

The technical condition is satisfied for instance by subsets with smooth boundary like in your question when $A$ is a ball and $B$ is the union of two balls.

Laczkovich's proof was nonconstructive and used AC (axiom of choice), but it was improved in

A. Marks, S. T. Unger, 
[Borel circle squaring](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26395654?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). Ann. of Math. (2) 186 (2017), no. 2, 581–605.

who gave a constructive proof which does not rely upon AC.

Edit: I just noticed that a very similar question was asked earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566639/can-tarskis-circle-squaring-problem-be-solved-with-measurable-sets-and-or-witho?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you! I keep meaning to read tye Marks-Unger paper in detail. I guess this is a good excuse to do it now.

Comment: @Ha! I had forgotten that previous question. I'll update it later tonight.